# Vue JS - How can i scroll (focus) to the 'Active' li element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an unordered list with a bunch of li elements inside. When using the arrow keys to move up and down the list (which highlights the current one and sets the Active class to true of that li element), I want the modal to scroll (focus) on the li element which has the class of Active set to true.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? I had no trouble finding answers googling "vue scroll to certain element on page". There's even a Vue NPM package you could use.

Comment: Or just google "javascript `Element.scrollIntoView()`"

Comment: I have tried
this.$el.getElementsByClassName("active")[0]scrollIntoView(); but want it to only start scrolling once I reach the bottom of the visible li elements in the modal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by model? the viewport of the user?

Then you will need to create a method and call it, with something along the lines of the following:

```
 window.scrollBy({
   top: targetYourElementHere.getBoundingClientRect().top,
   behavior: 'smooth'
 })
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant modal*. I was hoping that as I key down the down arrow, and get to the bottom of the list on the screen, it will start to scroll down the list to the other li elements.

Comment: No worries, so yeah that applies, a method to be called straight after you assign the active class to the li element.

Comment: To add, I wouldn't use "scrollIntoView()" as is not very well supported so far: https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview while scrollby() is pretty much supported everywhere.